# Monitoring Domain Availability

Tags: domains, domain-registration, whois, availability

How can I write a tool to monitor domain name availability? In particular, I am interested in monitoring availability of a domain which is in `PENDINGDELETE` (or `REDEMPTIONPERIOD` or `REGISTRY-DELETE-NOTIFY` or `PENDINGRESTORE` or similar ) status after its expiration date.

Any suggestions or more information about the `PENDINGDELETE` and similar status are also welcome (what is the time frame till which it can remain in this status, etc. I usually don't see a fixed pattern or even consistent correlation with expiration date and this status).

Answer (score 1):

You should look into how GoDaddy has built there tool, http://www.godaddy.com/domainaddon/domain-alert.aspx.

You probably do a whois on each domain someone is interested in on a server and then post that information to a web page.

Also, for more information on what PENDINGDELETE is, checkout http://www.domainpunch.com/support/articles/domainstatus.php.

Answer (score 0):

If the domain is registered at registrar A and registrar A offers a "domain name watch and buy" service, use their service. If the registrar does not offer such service, one of the best options (as far as people reporting seeing a greater chance of success) is snapnames.com